# Retrieve objects from many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I'm using Entity Framework Code First and I have the following objects in my model:

```
public class Category {
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ), Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength( 128 ), Index( IsUnique = true)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article {
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ), Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength( 128 ), Index]
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I'm implementing a method in my Data Access Layer to retrieve all `Articles` that are in one of the selected `Categories`:

```
IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles( int[] categoryIds );
```

My problem:  How do I build the query expression? If I were doing this in SQL, I'd write a query like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Articles a
JOIN ArticlesInCategories AS aic ON a.ArticleId = aic.ArticleId
JOIN Categories AS c on aic.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
WHERE c.CategoryId IN ( . . . )
```

So does that mean I'd write this like this?

```
return ( from a in context.Articles
         join c in context.Categories ON a.CategoryId = c.CatgegoryId
         where categoryIds.Contains( c.CategoryId ) );
```

The only problem is that the `Article` class doesn't have a `CategoryId` property.

How do I build this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse your query and use [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
return ( from c in context.Categories
         where categoryIds.Contains( c.CategoryId ) )
        .SelectMany(category => category.Arcticles);
```